# mySQL - Pass id to nested query

Tags: mysql, nested, sum

I am trying to get the sum of the sums of two different columns from the same table, grouped by user. The problem is, one of sums I have to find, requires some additional paramters.

Table 1:

```
userid, fname, lname
```

Table 2:

```
assigned_to (is = to userid from other table), 
est_hours (est = Estimate hours),
act_hours (act = Actual Hours), 
completed_date
```

I only want the est_hours from entries that have been marked as completed (by containing a value in the column completed_date. act_hours will be blank if completed_date is blank)

The problem with my query is I am not getting the correct values for the sum of the act_hours and est_hours. I think it has to do with the nested query not matching up the right userid.
Query:

```
SELECT userid, 
       fname, 
       lname, 
       SUM(act_hours)+(SELECT SUM(est_hours) 
                       from Table2 
                       WHERE completed_date IS NULL) AS total_hours 
FROM TABLE2, 
TABLE1 
WHERE TABLE1.userid = TABLE2.assigned_to 
GROUP BY userid;
```

I know I need to somehow pass the userid from the OUTER query, into the inner query, so that the SUM(est_hours) is only getting the sum for that user.

I keep going in circles and my brain hurts, so any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is valid in SQL Server, try it in MYSQL, may work:

```
SELECT userid, 
       fname, 
       lname, 
       (SELECT SUM(est_hours)+SUM(act_hours) 
                       from Table2 
                       WHERE completed_date IS NULL and TABLE2.assigned_to=TABLE1.userid) AS total_hours 
FROM 
TABLE1
```

OKAY, reverting back to my original query...

```
SELECT userid, 
       fname, 
       lname, 
       SUM(act_hours)+(SELECT SUM(est_hours) 
                       from Table2 
                       WHERE completed_date IS NULL 
                       AND Table2.assigned_to=Table1.userid) 
       AS total_hours 
FROM TABLE2, 
TABLE1 
WHERE TABLE1.userid = TABLE2.assigned_to 
GROUP BY userid;
```

Comment: -1, valid syntax it is, but the outcome is not the same, because `act_hours` should not be effected by the `where completed_date IS NULL`

Comment: Doesnt quite work. Your query uses the parameter of completed_date is null on both est_hours and act_hours. But the act_hours will only contain a value of greater than zero when it is marked as completed and a date is entered into the completed_date.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not use implicit join syntax, it's an anti-pattern**

Use explicit joins instead:

```
SELECT 
  t1.userid, 
  t1.fname, 
  t1.lname, 
  SUM(t2.act_hours)+(SELECT SUM(t3.est_hours) 
                     FROM Table2 t3
                     WHERE t3.completed_date IS NULL
                       AND t3.assigned_to = t1.userid) AS total_hours 
FROM table2 t2
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON (t1.userid = t2.assigned_to)
GROUP BY userid;
```

The solution to your headache is to use table aliases, then you can refer to different instances of the same table.
I strongly advice to always refix all fields with the table alias, so there can be no confusion which (instance of which) table the field comes from.
This will also shorten your lines and make your query more readable.

Comment: there is a loos ')' on the 2nd to last line.. Where is the '(' supposed to go?